Где найти гайды по "WCF" .NET Core - System.ServiceModel?
Приходиться делать интеграцию на SOAP-сервис с помощью "add reference" инструмента VS, который генерирует WSDL-клиента.
Хотелось бы узнать где можно почитать больше про сгенерированного клиента.
Как работают Bindings, ChannelFactory и прочие вещи.
Если знаете какие-то ресурсы буду признателен.

Смотрите офф документацию. В прошлые годы рекомендовали книги "Основы WCF для .NET", Резник, Крейн, Боуэн и "Создание служб WCF", Лёве (именно их я листал когда-то).

Когда ищете ресурсы, всегда уточняйте, какими языками владеете. Только русским или английский тоже подойдёт. / Хотя в любом случае такие вопросы оффтопик для SO.
